# Convert SMS address to Company Name and logo

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sms, flutter-android

In flutter, I read devices' SMS using the [SMS plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/sms).
After reading the SMS got the following properties in each SMS.

- id
- threadId
- address
- body

In **address** it contains Sender address for example **QP-KOTAKB** for **Kotak Mahindra Bank** and **VP-ViCARE** for **Vodafone Idea**.

In some of the android Messages App. Instead of Sender Address, they show the name and logo of the sender. Attached is an Example below.

[image: A messaging showing company name and logo]

**Question**:: How Can I implement this feature? Showing Company Name and Logo instead of the sender address for all SMSs.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are seeing - but it sounds like [Verified Business Messaging from Google](https://developers.google.com/business-communications/verified-sms/guides/learn).

Comment: What does this have to do with iOS (other than that Flutter also run there)?

Comment: @DeanTaylor Thanks I will look more in-depth at Google Verified Business. So you are saying I can verify all the messages in my inbox? Which are Verified Business by google.

Comment: @meaning-matters I tagged IOS in case Android and IOS have different mechanisms to do so. ( Not in all cases the same case runs on IOS. In some cases different configurations are required for Android and IOS )

Answer (score -1):

yes, its google's Verified SMS . you can its service providers like - Nirav Patel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).